# Simple 3D box-to-polygon collision

Tags: .net, f#, collision-detection

I have a 3D environment with pseudorandomly generated terrain (which is made up of triangles). I want to simply *detect* if a 3D bounding box and one of the terrain triangles have collided; how can I do this? I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558088/c-sharp-simple-3d-collision-detection) question which is pretty much exactly what I want, but the answer isn't satisfactory as it basically provides just an AABB algorithm...

PS: the triangles are defined with 3 3D points, and the bounding box can be defined by its 8 vertices.

Comment: Could you explain more fully why that isn't satisfactory?  It clearly was to that asker and we have no way of knowing why it isn't to you.

Comment: From the answer: "the following method ... will accept a BoundingBox object and determine if it is inside the the current instance of a BoundingBox. ... Here is the method to detect if one box is within the other, and if so, modifiy the box to move it outside." I don't understand how the answerer is answering the question; it looks to me like they are providing a method for detecting and reacting to an AABB-AABB collision (no triangles involved). If my understanding is wrong, please tell me!

Answer (score 1):

To do collision detection between a box and a random shape (assuming only straight sides), determine if any of the points of the shape are contained inside the box.  Basically something like this (pseudo-code):

```
let objectsCollide boundingBox shape
    shape.vertexes
    |> Seq.forall (fun v -> boundingBox <|> vertex
    |> not

let (<|>) a b = 
    let vertex = a.vertexes[0]
    vertex.neighbors
    |> Seq.forall (fun neighbor ->if b is between v and neighbor
                                      return false
                                  else 
                                      true
    |> not
```

There are implementations for a variety of intersection problems [here](http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/Intersection.html) (in c++).  The one you will want to use will be the intersection of triangles with a line segment, which you will need to repeat for each line segment in your bounding box (all combinations of vectors in the box).

Comment: Thought of that, but it won't cover quite all the cases (triangle could be sort of "skewered" by its face on a corner of the box). Although, the algorithm I'm going to use for now is an extension of this: it will take the average of each vertex to get 3 more points on the edges of the triangle, then take the averages of those to get 3 points on the actual face, and test each of these 9 points using an AABB collision test. Should work for now, but I expect it would be a bumpy ride for the box...

Comment: There is an implementation for this in C++ here: http://www.geometrictools.com/LibMathematics/Intersection/Intersection.html I would post it in the answer, but it's quite long.

Comment: I did update my answer with more on what you will need to do with the implementation I linked in order to adapt it to your problem.